# datetime function which converts yyyymm input to start and end of month date output

Tags: python, datetime

I’m new to using datetime

From an input in yyyymm (int)

```
input = 202003
```

I would like to create a function which converts this into an int variable yyyymmdd of the first and last days of that month, in this case:

```
start = 20200301
end =  20200331
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked out the datetime documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the calendar package:

```
import calendar
def get_start_end_month(input_):

    input_ = str(input_)

    year = int(input_[:4])
    month = int(input_[4:])

    start = int(input_+"01")
    end = int(input_+str(calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]))

    return start, end
```

Here the input is an int but I recommend using strings to deal with datetimes

Comment: Thanks Bruno. Is there a quick way of getting a string output from month mm. I.e. 03 to “March”

Comment: Yes, this will do: datetime.strptime("03", "%m").strftime("%B"), just change the 03 for whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

**CODE:**

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

string = "202003" #--> Your input string
start = datetime.strptime(string, "%Y%m").date()

nextmonth = 1 if start.month == 12 else start.month + 1 # --> if current month is 12 cycle to 1
year = start.year + 1 if nextmonth == 1 else start.year

end = date(year, nextmonth, 1) - timedelta(days=1)

print("start:", start)
print("end:", end)
```

**For Example:**

If input `string` is `202003` the output will be,

```
start: 2020-03-01
end: 2020-03-31
```

If input `string` is `202002` the output will be,

```
start: 2020-02-01
end: 2020-02-29
```

If input `string` is `202012` the output will be,

```
start: 2020-12-01
end: 2020-12-31
```